# Mysql read parsing is giving whitespace chars in cli

Tags: mysql, shell, stdin, xargs

I am making a mysql call to the database that give me the results line by line to standard output like so:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -D table -s -N -e "select * from test_table"
```

And it gives back an output like this:

```
result1
result2
```

Which is what I want.

The problem is when I am then trying to read and use those outputs it doesn't work for example:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -D table -s -N -e "select * from test_table" | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo "Processing % now";'
```

or

```
 mysql -u root -h localhost -D table -s -N -e "select * from test_table" | while read -e testRes ; do
                echo "Processing $testRes now";
    done
```

Prints out this

```
 nowessing result1
 nowessing result2
```

And if only the result is given to echo it prints this:

```
result1

result2
```

So I think the standard input is reading wrong what the MYSQL tables is giving me, maybe my IFS is wrong or another problem. That is causing the new line to be added

Comment: What OS? What shell ?

Comment: What happens if you try | xargs printf "processing %s now\n"

Comment: Amazon linux, zsh